# Selenium find an element and check if it's interactable

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

This is my code:

```
label = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//label[contains(.,"{}")]'.format("XYZ"))

if label:
     check if we can click this element (label[0]) if it's not clickable, continue.
```

Is it possible to find an element and then check if it's clickable?.

Normally this issue happened with webpages where when click button something else appeared. This means that element exists BUT you can't interact with him. How to handle this error or ignore and continue?

**P.S.** Similar question already asked several times, BUT I can't see the answer which will fit my needs. Solutions like `implicitly_wait(1)` and e.t.c. are not what I'm looking for.

Comment: _Is it possible to find an element and then check if it's clickable?_ Yes? Can you clarify what exactly your question is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Clean method to check if selected XPath is interactable (if it's VISIBLE)

Comment: @AMC basically a layer which will do -> element exist? -> if yes, -> is it visible -> if yes -> click (of send_keys and e.t.c.))

Comment: How about using `.is_displayed()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used `.is_displayed()` which solved my issue.

- Find element x
- `x[0].is_displayed()`
- if `True` carry on

Comment: Condition could be ***and***ed with `.is_enabled()`.